# Source installation of Fuerte but pcl dependency problem

Tags: pcl, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi.
I'm installing ROS Fuerte by source intallation.
I have followed below tutorial
http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation/Ubuntu/Source
However, there are two problems.

**First is following. It seems pcl dependency problem.**

hyon@hyon-gt683dx:~/ros/visualization/rviz$ rosdep install -a
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
carrot_planner: Missing resource pcl
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/home/hyon/ros/navigation
ROS path [2]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [3]=/home/hyon/ros/common
ROS path [4]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [5]=/home/hyon/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [6]=/home/hyon/ros/simulator_gazebo
ROS path [7]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [8]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry
ROS path [9]=/home/hyon/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [10]=/home/hyon/ros/bullet
ROS path [11]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model
ROS path [12]=/home/hyon/ros/xacro
ROS path [13]=/home/hyon/ros/image_transport_plugins
ROS path [14]=/home/hyon/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [15]=/home/hyon/ros/stage
ROS path [16]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [17]=/home/hyon/ros/driver_common
ROS path [18]=/home/hyon/ros/physics_ode
ROS path [19]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [20]=/home/hyon/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [21]=/home/hyon/ros/bond_core
ROS path [22]=/home/hyon/ros/image_common
ROS path [23]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [24]=/home/hyon/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [25]=/home/hyon/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [26]=/home/hyon/ros/bfl
ROS path [27]=/home/hyon/ros/image_pipeline
ROS path [28]=/home/hyon/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [29]=/home/hyon/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [30]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [31]=/home/hyon/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [32]=/home/hyon/ros/vision_opencv
ROS path [33]=/home/hyon/ros/visualization
ROS path [34]=/home/hyon/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [35]=/home/hyon/ros/slam_gmapping
ROS path [36]=/home/hyon/ros/filters
ROS path [37]=/home/hyon/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [38]=/home/hyon/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [39]=/home/hyon/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [40]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [41]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [42]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros

So I have installed PCL by doing followings

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all

Also there is a problem when I'm doing rosmake.

[rospack] Error: package/stack costmap_2d depends on non-existent package pcl

It also seems pcl problem.
Do you have some advice?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38842/source-installation-of-fuerte-but-pcl-dependency-problem/) by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on ROS Answers with karma: 314 on 2012-07-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In Fuerte, PCL will be treated as standalone library, not as a package of ROS. From http://ros.org/wiki/fuerte, Section 4- Migration :

```
pcl: should now be used as a standard system dependency, which means you must update your CMakeLists.txt to link against them directly and add include directories as appropriate.
```

You had already install pcl, you shall update CMakeLists.txt to reflect include directories and link directories

---

Originally posted by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) with karma: 660 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-07-17**:
No. I have a problem during install a ROS in my machine. Not a migration.

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-07-17**:
This is my problem................... hyon@hyon-t61:~$ rosdep install -a
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
carrot_planner: Missing resource pcl

**Comment by [Hyon Lim](https://answers.ros.org/users/378/hyon-lim/) on 2012-07-17**:
hyon@hyon-t61:~$ rosdep install -a
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
carrot_planner: Missing resource pcl

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-17**:
answer is still valid.

**Comment by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on 2012-07-17**:
Is your problem resolved?

**Comment by [John Hoare](https://answers.ros.org/users/159/john-hoare/) on 2012-08-02**:
I am having the same problem. As far as I can tell this looks like it is some problem with rosdep. I am just following the Ubuntu Source Install instructions directly as posted.